# How to Run hydraulic Single Step Simulation in Java reading from existing ".inp" file

Tags: java

.inp file is an extension of Epanet.
I just want to develop simple iteration in Java.
But I can not read from file(.inp).

I want to run hydraulic simulation with following steps:

1. Read an .inp file as input network
2. Put number of links and number of nodes in `NomLinks` and `NomNodes`
3. Set some pipes status (closed or open), and get start node and finish node index of these pipes
4. Set emitter of some nodes by using node index
5. Run a single step hydraulic simulation and save each nodes pressure and index in an array

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to be able to help you here, I suggest you try https://www.epa.gov/water-research/forms/more-information-about-epanet

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Epanet is a well accepted hydraulic solver. Many programming language are used to develope softwares but Java is kinda new for epanet. 

someone who is interesting with this field may answer me.